# GPU Passthrough on Xen Hypervisor

Tags: xen, dell-poweredge, gpu, pv, hvm

I have a Dell PowerEdge r710 running the Xen hypervisor and I want to get a decent graphics card for a virtual machine. I plan on doing GPU passthrough to dedicate the entire GPU to the virtual machine for increased performance and I am wondering what GPU I should buy for this task.

Because I am putting it in a server, the GPU can't have any external power connectors, as a server's power supply does not have cables for GPUs. I'm pretty sure the GPU's PCI bracket needs to be half-height as well for it to fit.

I'm not sure whether to do a paravirtualized virtual machine or an HVM virtual machine for this, as I have heard good and bad things about both and I don't know which of them best supports GPU passthrough. Also, the guest operating system that I will virtualize is OpenSUSE.

If you have any ideas, please share. Thanks!

Comment: A R710 is pretty old. What use you want to do? as most game server side got only cli. The GPU is rarely used. You know at that age a old refurb pc tower would be probably faster

Comment: I know this. I need to use GPU passthrough to a VM for rendering and stuff. I'm going to try the Radeon Pro WX 3100 for now.